# UNIX - How to swap characters under particular column in UNIX

Tags: unix

I have below two lines in a file.txt I want the last two digits in the third column to swap from 01 to 10 and save the two new records in new file. The length of the other columns will be changing, but the length of the third column will remain 11 digits only. Could you please help here.

```
1234567;Kottadi Kannan;12345678901;ABC
7654321;Ram Kumar;98765432201;CBA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a solution using POSIX [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and `substr()` to ‘rebuild’ the string with some hard-coded indices (it’s not pretty or concise, but it works):

```sh
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '
{ $3 = substr($3, 1, 9) substr($3, 11, 1) substr($3, 10, 1); print }
' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

But *if* the value is always an integer and it should *always* change from `…01` to `…10` then it can be made a lot simpler:

```sh
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{ $3 += 9; print }' file.txt > newfile.txt
```

Comment: Yeah its always integer and last two digits should change from 01 to 10. It worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -ri 's/(^.*;)(.*;)(.*)([[:digit:]])([[:digit:]])(;.*$)/\1\2\3\5\4\6/' file
```

Enable regular expression interpretation with -E or -r and then split the lines into 6 section specified with parenthesis. Substitute the line for the 1st to 3rd sections before switching the 4th and 5th sections followed by the 6th.

Comment: Neat, but I'd combine the match for everything before the 2 digits like so: `.*;.*;.*`, and replace with `\1`, which leads to a cleaner match & simpler replacement string.